# Options aren't visible for angular-ng-autocomplete but can click and select

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using **[angular-ng-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete)** NPM package to show suggestions in a drop-down menu. It seems to be working fine when there's only one input field, but as soon as I add other input fields with ng-autocomplete component, the options/suggestions are only visible for last input field.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  queryForm: FormGroup;
  keyword = {
    countries: 'name',
    cities: 'city_name',
    areas: 'area_name'
  };

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.queryForm = fb.group({
   country: ['', Validators.required],
   city: ['', Validators.required],
   area: ['', Validators.required]
  });
 }

  public countries = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Japan',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'India',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'China',
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Russia',
    }
  ];
  public cities = [
    {
      id: 115,
      city_name: 'Kolkata',
    },
    {
      id: 116,
      city_name: 'Bangalore',
    },
    {
      id: 118,
      city_name: 'Delhi',
    },
    {
      id: 117,
      city_name: 'Mumbai',
    }
  ]
  public areas = [
    {
      id: 19,
      area_name: 'area1',
    },
    {
      id: 20,
      area_name: 'area 2',
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      area_name: 'some area',
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      area_name: 'another area',
    }
  ]
  selectEvent(item) {
    // do something with selected item
  }

  onChangeSearch(search: string) {
    // fetch remote data from here
    // And reassign the 'data' which is binded to 'data' property.
  }

  onFocused(e) {
    // do something
  }

  onSubmit(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Angular autocomplete
  </h1>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="queryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(queryForm.value)" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="country mt-25">
    <div class="ng-autocomplete">
      <ng-autocomplete
        formControlName="country"
        [data]="countries"
        [searchKeyword]="keyword.countries"
        placeHolder="Enter the Country Name"
        (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
        (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
        (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
        [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
        [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
      </ng-autocomplete>

      <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
        <a [innerHTML]="item.name"></a>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
        <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="city mt-25">
    <div class="ng-autocomplete">
      <ng-autocomplete
        formControlName="city"
        [data]="cities"
        [searchKeyword]="keyword.cities"
        placeHolder="Enter the City Name"
        (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
        (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
        (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
        [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
        [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
      </ng-autocomplete>

      <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
        <a [innerHTML]="item.city_name"></a>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
        <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="area mt-25">
    <div class="ng-autocomplete">
      <ng-autocomplete
        [data]="areas"
        formControlName="area"
        [searchKeyword]="keyword.areas"
        placeHolder="Enter Area Name"
        (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
        (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
        (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
        [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
        [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
      </ng-autocomplete>

      <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
        <a [innerHTML]="item.area_name"></a>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
        <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-25">
    <button [disabled]="queryForm.invalid">Submit Query</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm not sure if it's a bug in the npm package or I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated. You can also check [demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-autocomplete-jw521n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using three `ng-autocomplete` elements and all of them are referring to the same `[itemTemplate]` and `[notFoundTemplate]`. You just have to point each element's `[itemTemplate]` and `[notFoundTemplate]` to their respective templates. Try this:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Angular autocomplete
  </h1>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="queryForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(queryForm.value)" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="country mt-25">
    <div class="ng-autocomplete">
      <ng-autocomplete
        formControlName="country"j
        [data]="countries"
        [searchKeyword]="keyword.countries"
        placeHolder="Enter the Country Name"
        (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
        (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
        (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
        [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
        [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate">
      </ng-autocomplete>

      <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
        <a [innerHTML]="item.name"></a>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
        <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="city mt-25">
    <div class="ng-autocomplete">
      <ng-autocomplete
        formControlName="city"
        [data]="cities"
        [searchKeyword]="keyword.cities"
        placeHolder="Enter the City Name"
        (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
        (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
        (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
        [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate2"
        [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate2">
      </ng-autocomplete>

      <ng-template #itemTemplate2 let-item>
        <a [innerHTML]="item.city_name"></a>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #notFoundTemplate2 let-notFound>
        <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="area mt-25">
    <div class="ng-autocomplete">
      <ng-autocomplete
        [data]="areas"
        formControlName="area"
        [searchKeyword]="keyword.areas"
        placeHolder="Enter Area Name"
        (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
        (inputChanged)='onChangeSearch($event)'
        (inputFocused)='onFocused($event)'
        [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate3"
        [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate3">
      </ng-autocomplete>

      <ng-template #itemTemplate3 let-item>
        <a [innerHTML]="item.area_name"></a>
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #notFoundTemplate3 let-notFound>
        <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mt-25">
    <button [disabled]="queryForm.invalid">Submit Query</button>
  </div>
</form>
```